# In R how do I append to a list and then address different named elements of the list?

Tags: r

I have a series of steps (or a loop) in a program and each step returns a named list.  At the end of the steps or loop I want to average each element of the list separately.

In the example below, a separate X, Y and Z value are returned for each step, and I will want to take the mean of the Xs, the Ys, and the Zs separately.

I tried this:

```
foo = list()
foo = append(foo,list(x=10,y=11,z=12))
foo = append(foo,list(x=100,y=110,z=120))
```

But that code gives me this result:

```
foo // hit enter here
$x
10
$y
11
$z
12
$x
100
$y
110
$z
120
```

and no matter what I try I cannot get at the two values of X to take the mean of them.

```
foo$x // hit enter here
10
```

How do I get the expected result for something like  `mean(foo$x)`, `mean(foo$y)`, and `mean(foo$z)`?

It is entirely possible that the list is not the correct type to use, if so please suggest a better type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `append` to a list, you will just add the elements to the end. There is no uniqueness enforced on list names so you won't be able to get the elements named the same easily. Instead, use a data frame and `rbind` your elements (for minimal changes to your code):

```r
foo <- data.frame()
foo <- rbind(foo, list(x = 10, y = 11, z = 12))
foo <- rbind(foo, list(x = 100, y = 110, z = 120))
foo
#>     x   y   z
#> 1  10  11  12
#> 2 100 110 120
mean(foo$x)
#> [1] 55
```

If you give some more insight into your data generating process then better solutions with apply or collecting results in a list are probably also available.

Answer (score 1):

Use tapply with mean on the foo unlisted.

```
tapply(unlist(foo), names(foo), mean)
##    x    y    z 
## 55.0 60.5 66.0
```

It would be better to create foo as a named numeric vector rather than a list in which case we would not have to unlist it.

```
foo = c()
foo = c(foo, x = 10, y = 11, z = 12)
foo = c(foo, x = 100, y = 110, z = 120)
tapply(foo, names(foo), mean)
##    x    y    z 
## 55.0 60.5 66.0
```

or

```
foo = c()
foo = c(foo, c(x = 10, y = 11, z = 12))
foo = c(foo, c(x = 100, y = 110, z = 120))
tapply(foo, names(foo), mean)
##    x    y    z 
## 55.0 60.5 66.0
```

It would also be possible to reshape it into a matrix:

```
m <- do.call("cbind", tapply(foo, names(foo), c)); m
##     x   y   z
## x  10  11  12
## x 100 110 120

colMeans(m)
##   x    y    z 
## 55.0 60.5 66.0
```

Comment: Would you please show how you would append to the numeric vector?  Replacing `list` with `c` did not work, i just get the same result except the vector is horizontal and I can't access elements by name

Comment: Have moved comment to answer.